# Environment with comma separated optional arguments

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

Using `xparse`, how does one get something like this to work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ anenvironment }{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o }{
  \begin{ auxanenvironment }[#1]
}{
  \end{ auxanenvironment }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ auxanenvironment }{ O{}o }{
  Do~something~with~#1\IfValueTF{ #2 }{ ,~and~something~else~with~#2. }{ . }
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{anenvironment}[this argument, this other argument]
\end{anenvironment}

\begin{anenvironment}[this argument]
\end{anenvironment}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's possible to do it with an auxiliary environment, I don't think it's the best way to do it.

You should also deal with the case when the optional argument doesn't appear: it's optional, isn't it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{anenvironment}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o }
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}{ \noibe_anenvironment_arg:nn #1 }
  %<initial code for the environment>
  \par Start\par
 }
 {
  %<final code for the environment>
  End\par
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \noibe_anenvironment_arg:nn
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #1 }
   {
    Do~something~with~#1
    \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
     {.}
     {
      ,~and~something~else~with~#2.
     }
   }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{anenvironment}[this argument, this other argument]
\end{anenvironment}

\medskip

\begin{anenvironment}[this argument]
\end{anenvironment}

\medskip

\begin{anenvironment}
\end{anenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without knowing your real use case, it's difficult to be less generic. I suggest you to consider a key-value interface, if the argument is for setting options.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newenvironment{anenvironment}[1][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
    \readlist*\arglist{ #1}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\arglist[]{%
      Doing something with \detokenize\expandafter{\x}.\x\par
    }%
  \fi\par
}{%
  \par Done doing something.\par\medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{anenvironment}
This is a test.
\end{anenvironment}
\begin{anenvironment}[\itshape]
This is a test.
\end{anenvironment}
\begin{anenvironment}[\itshape,\bfseries, \tiny]
This is a test.
\end{anenvironment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the right way to do it, but I just found out that removing the square braces around the argument on line 6, and changing `auxanenvironment`'s arguments to mandatory solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ anenvironment }{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}o }{
  \begin{ auxanenvironment }#1
}{
  \end{ auxanenvironment }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ auxanenvironment }{ mm }{
  Do~something~with~#1\IfValueTF{ #2 }{ ,~and~something~else~with~#2. }{ . }
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{anenvironment}[this argument, this other argument]
\end{anenvironment}

\begin{anenvironment}[this argument]
\end{anenvironment}
\end{document}
```